# Why does this RegExp exec cause an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following block of code:

```
var field,
    reg = new RegExp('{{.*?}}', 'i'),
    text = 'This is a string with 1: {{param1}}, 2: {{param2}} and 3: {{param3}} parameters.';

while (field = reg.exec(text)) {
    console.log(field);
}
```

If I include a `g` global flag, the loop runs fine. But, if it's not global, surely `reg.exec(text);` should return `null` after just the first match and end the `while` loop?

Trying to understand the reason behind it, if somebody can elaborate I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What happens if you escape the `{` and `}`?

Comment: Why you're not capturing the pattern (`()`)?

Comment: @npinti, the same I'm afraid.

Comment: @Xlander, same result I'm afraid.

Comment: [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) "Note: Do not place the regular expression literal (or RegExp constructor) within the while condition or it will create an infinite loop if there is a match due to the lastIndex property being reset upon each iteration. **Also be sure that the global flag is set or a loop will occur here also.**"

Answer (score 22):

The MDN documentation for [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) has what I think is the answer when explaining the value of the `lastIndex` property of the RegExp object:

> The index at which to start the next match. **When "g" is absent, this will remain as 0.**

So each time you call `.exec()` on that RegExp object, it will start from the *beginning* of the string again. If there's at least one match, that means it will always find a match, and your loop will never end.

Comment: Well spotted, ha! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6):

Its because [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) combined with `g` flag actually mutates the start index of the RegExp instance itself.

On the other hand without `g` flag, it does not mutate, therefore it returns always the first result, if it matches your while loop will go gorilla.